# CSS Responsive help for fix

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem: I edited the views with CCS codes, on the Iphone 11 Pro the view fits, on the desktop too, but on an Iphone 12 Pro the button is moved.

It's also shifted a bit on the tablet.

My CSS code is so confusing that I don't know what is what.

Please note the quantity button, it is about this button with which you can select the number of how much you want to buy of the same product.

you can see it here on the website, the quantity button moves across different views:

https://glowsring.com/produkt/azure-falls/

```css
.quantity.buttons_added.form-flat {
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex !important;
  margin-left: 163px;
}

@media(max-width:600px) {
  .quantity.buttons_added.form-flat {
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 43px;
  }
  .elementor-5398 .elementor-element.elementor-element-6514beb .wl-atc-button-area table tr td {
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -51px;
  }
}

.elementor-5398 .elementor-element.elementor-element-6514beb .wl-atc-button-area .quantity input {
  font-family: "Roboto", Sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  width: 110px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px -10px 0px 0px;
  padding: 4.6px 0px 0px 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .wl .wl-atc-button-area table select {
    background-color: #0000;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-align-last: center;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
  .wl .wl-atc-button-area table select {
    background-color: #0000;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-align-last: center;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
  .elementor-5398 .elementor-element.elementor-element-6514beb .wl-atc-button-area table tr td {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media(max-width:759px) {
  .quantity.buttons_added.form-flat {
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
  }
}

.elementor-5398 .elementor-element.elementor-element-6514beb .wl-atc-button-area table tr td {
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .quantity.buttons_added.form-flat {
    margin-left: 53px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you need the offending button to be centered?

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS yes for every view

Comment: I placed an answer. Sorry if it's a little bit unfinished but I'm on my mobile and editing options are very limited in this version of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details (this includes HTML). Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428). Also flag more carfully and read the description of the tags. I fail to see what the question has to do with `designer` or `javascript`.

Comment: @tacoshy look very good, but unfortunately the button changes again on an Iphone 12 Pro, I see the problem, with an Iphone 11 Pro everything looks centered, also on the Ipad Air 2 it looks almost centered, just like on the desktop , strange that the centering of an Iphone 12 Pro is not set correctly.

Comment: here is the Iphone 12 Pro view https://ibb.co/Qk0Y68S

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.quantity.buttons_added.form-flat { 
  width: -webkit-fill-available; 
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
  display: flex !important; 
  justify-content: center; 
}
```

and comment for a while all other references to the `.quantity.buttons` in your css and see if it meets your needs. If it does then delete all the commented references.

The displacement of the button is caused by the `margin-left` property set on each reference as it is a general margin that would not fit in every screen. If the screen with it's the appropriate then the button will be centered but if the screen is a little wider or smaller it will fail centering the button.

Comment: As you stated that you have troubled formatting while writing on a mobile device, I tooked the liberty to give you a hand with the formatting part.

Comment: Hey thank you but the script does not work

Comment: Did you commented all the `@media` references to the offending button?

Answer (score 0):

Its a dodgy override due to other !important's being used in the styling, but the majority of the misplacement is down to the margin-left, and margin-right properties.

You could centre it with the following:

```
.quantity.buttons_added.form-flat {
   display: block!important;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```